# Integrate swift in objective c framewok

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am starting a objective framework and wanna integrating some swift code in it. according to the official document. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78)

> Because the generated header for a framework target is part of the framework’s public interface, only declarations marked with the public modifier appear in the generated header for a framework target. You can still use Swift methods and properties that are marked with the internal modifier from within the Objective-C part of your framework, as long they are declared within a class that inherits from an Objective-C class.

However, I found it is impossible to access internal part of swift like:

@objc
internal class A: NSObject {}

Comment: When you ask for help, please include a clear question.

Comment: lol, thanks! I dont know what was I thinking during typing :O

Answer (score 0):

The quote says “you can still use Swift **methods and properties** that are marked with the internal modifier” (emphasis added). In your example it is the *class* (not a method or property) which is `internal`. If you make the class `public` and add an internal method, you should be able to access that method.

**edit**: The following works for me:

Swift:

```
@objc public class MyClass : NSObject {
    internal func bar() -> String { return "foobar" }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
#import "MyApplication-Swift.h"

MyClass *foo = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [foo bar]);
```

Note that the code must be built for the generated `MyApplication-Swift.h` to be updated.

Comment: Well, I just did an experiment where I declare a class: \@objc public class A: NSObject { \@objc internal func methodA(){} } and the method is still not accessible from objective c. In the auto generated Module-Swift.h file, there is a declaration of Class A without method, I suppose this is why I cant access that method from objective c. However, I dont know what else I can do to access swift in the same framework, any suggestions?

Comment: @tzx7788 See updated answer – works for me. Perhaps you didn't re-build the header?

Comment: hmm.., that's odd, I double checked it is not working for me:(. However to be more specific I am working on a framework not an application. Did you also do this in a framework? ( Application in this case is fine for me also)

Comment: @tzx7788 When trying it with a framework, XCode does not prompt me to add the bridging header upon creating a Swift file in an Objective-C project. Could be that it also doesn't set up whatever behind-the-scenes mechanism is used to create the `MyFramework-Swift.h` correctly. Perhaps try creating the project as an application, set up the swift, then just change the code and build target into a framework? (And submit a bug report to Apple.)

Comment: Thanks, as result, I have gave up mix swift and objective c. The framework will be pure objective c.